How to connect to an already launched jupyter server in Jupyterlab?
vscode has this functionality. It is described here.
But how can I do this in JupyterLab or Jupyter notebook?

Discussion thread about connecting to remote kernels here. Also see here and here and here and 'How do I add a kernel on a remote machine in IPython (Jupyter) Notebook?'.

I launch jupyter server:
jupyter server --ServerApp.ip="0.0.0.0" --ServerApp.port=8001 --IdentityProvider.token=${JUPYTER_TOKEN} --allow-root --allow_remote_access=true

And connect in jupyter lab:
jupyter lab --GatewayClient.url=http://localhost:8001 --GatewayClient.auth_token=$(JUPYTER_TOKEN)

Thanks Wayne.
